# Getting multiple records for same value in JSON

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

I am working on `WEB API`. I have created an `api` which gives me details. The details should be after `nth` interval. Below is my code.

```
var mainDetails = kesc.tj_xhqd.Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt)).AsEnumerable()
.Select((x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
.Where(x => x.i % interval == 0)
.ToList();

 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { details = mainDetails });
```

The output is

```
{
"details": [
    {
        "MSN": "002999001180",
        "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52",
        "PingValue": "19",
        "i": 0
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999001180",
        "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52",
        "PingValue": "19",
        "i": 24
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999001180",
        "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52",
        "PingValue": "19",
        "i": 48
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999001180",
        "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52",
        "PingValue": "19",
        "i": 72
    },
    {
        "MSN": "002999001180",
        "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52",
        "PingValue": "19",
        "i": 96
    },
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {
        "MSN": "002999001180",
        "PingDateTime": "2018-05-16T18:39:52",
        "PingValue": "19",
        "i": 144
    },
 ]
}
```

The `i` value is incremented but the other details are repeated again and again.
In actual the ping value comes after every 2 minutes, ping value can be same but not the date time.

**Update 1**

Below is my snapshot of the table taken directly from DB

[image]

From the above picture, it is clearly seen that only ping value i.e. 19 is repeated several times but the date time is only single but still the date time `2018-05-16T18:39:52` is shown multiple times

**Update 2**

Here is my DB context that will implement my model

```
public partial class kescEntities : DbContext
{
    public kescEntities()
        : base("name=kescEntities")
    {
        this.SetCommandTimeOut(10000);
    }
    public void SetCommandTimeOut(int Timeout)
    {
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<tj_xhqd> tj_xhqd { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set my query in a way that I can get all different records after the interval?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Currently unclear what it is you are asking.

Comment: @Nkosi actually I want to get every `nth` record in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code. Seems to be working as intended. It would seem that your problem lies with the data itself. **Have you checked your logic for storing data?** If there are duplicates in your data, naturally, duplicates will be retrieved.

**Edit:** 
I think there was a misunderstanding with the storing data part question. It's not how you store in the database I was asking, its how you were persisting the data. How do you persist your data or how the persistent data was stored? Was there any fetch logic before you arrived in this:

> var mainDetails = **kesc.tj_xhqd** <--- *This guy*

The part where I tested your code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();

            List<Chingamajig> chinga = new List<Chingamajig>();
            string[] verylongnum = new string[] { "00000000002312312", "34234002342342" };
            int[] somenum = new int[] { 7, 14, 12, 28 };

            for(int i = 0;i<100;i++)
            {
                Chingamajig c = new Chingamajig();

                c.VeryLongNumbers = verylongnum[r.Next(0, 2)];
                c.DateValue = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes((double)r.Next(-100, 101));
                c.SomeNumber = somenum[r.Next(0, 4)];
                chinga.Add(c);
            }

            foreach (Chingamajig c in chinga.OrderBy(x => x.VeryLongNumbers).ThenBy(y => y.DateValue).ThenBy(z => z.SomeNumber))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", c.VeryLongNumbers, c.DateValue, c.SomeNumber);
            }

            var m = "00000000002312312";
            var dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var interval = 2;

            var ee = chinga.Where(x => (x.VeryLongNumbers == m) && (x.DateValue >= dt)).AsEnumerable()
                .Select((z, i) => new { MSN = z.VeryLongNumbers, PingDT = z.DateValue, PingV = z.SomeNumber, i = i })
                .Where(x => x.i % interval == 0).ToList();

            Console.Clear();

            foreach(var n in ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2} : {3}", n.MSN, n.PingDT, n.PingV, n.i);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Chingamajig
    {
        public string VeryLongNumbers { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }
        public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

So yeah.. I did test your code with mock data because your sample code had little meat in it.

**Update:**
Try adding this to your code

```
var mainDetails = kesc.tj_xhqd
//This line
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt))
.AsEnumerable()
.Select((x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
.Where(x => x.i % interval == 0)
.ToList();
```

Not sure but this problem seems to be stemming from tables with no pkey. Not sure about your case though but below is a link for your reference
[Identical Rows](https://forums.asp.net/post/5925659.aspx)

Comment: Ping value can be duplicated but not the time

Comment: And also in the table, there only one record against the time `2018-05-16 18:39:52`. As it is the 1st record so only this one is showing multiple times

Comment: @MrFaisal I've edited my answer to explain further that its not about your data in the database but how that persistent data is stored/fetched.

Comment: There is no fetch logic only some `where` clauses.

Comment: @MrFaisal Then I really have no idea how you end up with that output. I even went on to create an API just to see if maybe there's a chance I can replicate your problem but your code still works. My json output is still unique/no duplicates in the data. Sorry dude.

Comment: Is there any chance that my query selects only 1st record?

Comment: @MrFaisal it is possible your DBContext or whatever you use to fetch data in your Model is fetching the same record while looping through the whole record in your table. You just have to investigate that part. Your LINQ query shouldn't return dupes if the object you are querying doesn't have dupes. Probably put a breakpoint so you can add watch and see the raw data before being sent as a response.

Comment: I'll give it a try again to debug

Comment: Ok now I'm really intruiged on how your program fetches your data. Can you post your dbcontext for populating you model?

Comment: @MrFaisal I've updated my post to show a possible solution.

Comment: Always glad to help! Cheers! :)